# OpenLayers export features with their styles

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to export features and then load them to map
Already I can save features and re-create them by Geojson object.

the problem is that GeoJson dosen't save feature's style.
what is the best way to save styles and load them with features?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: GeoJSON format does not support styles, if you need styles you should use KML format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below codes to save and load geojson file with styles.

add the following line to the header

```
<script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.0/FileSaver.min.js"></script> <!-- we will use it to download the geojson file -->
```

Then add the following function to the code.

```
function saveMap() {
    var mapLayers = map.getLayers().getArray();
    var features = [];
    mapLayers.forEach(function(layer) {

        if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector) {
            var layerFeatures = layer.getSource().getFeatures();
            layerFeatures.forEach(function(feature) {
                feature.setProperties(layer.getStyle()) //add the layer styles to the feature as properties
                features.push(feature);
            });
        }
    });
    var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    var geojsonString = geojsonFormat.writeFeatures(features, {
        featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()
    });
    var blob = new Blob([geojsonString], {
        type: 'text/plain'
    });
    saveAs(blob, 'map.geojson');
}
```

Load the map again with the styles in OpenLayers:

```
// Use jQuery to read the GeoJSON file
$.getJSON("map.geojson", function(data) {
    var geojson = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
        dataProjection: "EPSG:4326",
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    }).readFeatures(data);


    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: geojson,
        wrapX: false
    });

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
    })
    // Iterate through the features in a vector layer
    vectorLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature) {
        // Take the style  of the feature as a variable
        var fill_color = feature.values_[0].fill_.color_;
        var stroke_color = feature.values_[0].stroke_.color_;
        var stroke_width = feature.values_[0].stroke_.width_;

        // Create a style object 
        var style = new ol.style.Style({

            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: stroke_color,
                width: stroke_width
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: fill_color
            })
        });
        // Add the style to the feature
        feature.setStyle(style);
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

});
```

You can view the full code of the following links

[ol-save-geojson.html](https://gist.github.com/enisgetmez/d3dfa2cc96695657bf49967293a0d3f0)

[ol-read-geojson-styles.html](https://gist.github.com/enisgetmez/92506815bf09a470f41b9d41ac906bd4)

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Question: in setProperties why do you pass layer style?
all the features in your code has same style?

Comment: in OpenLayers, styles are generally written to the layer, so the feature styles will be empty. Therefore, I think it would be more accurate to retrieve the layer styles. If the styles are directly entered into the feature, you can edit the command to be feature.setProperties(feature.getStyle()), or you can use an if-else condition to use the layer style if the feature style is empty.